# How to typeset a text like a beamer enumerate item, rectangle style

Tags: beamer, enumerate

I would like to format a text so that it looks like an enumerate item.

In the example below, you can see that I would like a list that consists of the items 1,2,n. I would like the "n" to be typeset like the 1 and the 2, i.e. with a blue background.

```
\documentclass{beamer}


\usetheme{Madrid}
\useinnertheme{rectangles}
\setbeamertemplate{blocks}[default]


\begin{document}
    \begin{frame}
        \begin{enumerate}
            \item Item one
            \item Item two
            \item[n] Item n
        \end{enumerate}
    \end{frame}
\end{document}
```

Thanks!

Comment: Welcome to TeX.Stackexchange!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
\documentclass{beamer}


\usetheme{Madrid}
\useinnertheme{rectangles}
\setbeamertemplate{blocks}[default]

\newcommand{\mysquare}[1]{
  \hbox{%
    \usebeamerfont*{item projected}%
    \usebeamercolor[bg]{item projected}%
    \vrule width2.25ex height1.85ex depth.4ex%
    \hskip-2.25ex%
    \hbox to2.25ex{%
      \hfil%
      \color{fg}#1%
      \hfil}%
  }%
}


\begin{document}
    \begin{frame}
        \begin{enumerate}
            \item Item one
            \item Item two
            \item[\mysquare{n}] Item n
        \end{enumerate}
    \end{frame}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: A little followup: How did you figure that out? Did you look into the beamer sourcecode, or is there another way to find out the formatting of a special piece of text?

Comment: @Jan Source code. The original template for the enumeration with squares can be found in https://github.com/josephwright/beamer/blob/master/base/beamerbaseauxtemplates.sty

Comment: OK, so there is no easy way... Guess I'll have to come back here the next time I have a similar question ;-)